# Interactive slideshow prevents me from swiping to the next page?

Tags: epub

Created an ebook with InDesign and exported it as a Epub.

Functionality is working on a desktop computer, but not on an Ipad:
I have an interactive slideshow which lets me page through content on page 1. When I go to use Ipad's side-swiping nav functionality, the interactive slideshow overrides the Ipad side-swiping nav and won't let me navigate to page 2.